# Facebook API : Can I use public API(v2.x) without access token. (share count)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, share, public

Facebook link share count API
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com <--- v1.0 (current.. available)

but

is this available after version 2.x? (without access token)
I want use this API

reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can look into the future, but I doubt facebook will disable that endpoint again so soon, because the "new version" was only introduced with v2.1.

The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/url state that an Access Token is required for the usage of this endpoint. This means you can also use an App Access Token, which is easy to get. Just create a new app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. And after some research I find this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/10/26/extending-facebook-share/ .
You can try use this approach, it work with any version FB API:

```
FB.api({
                method: 'links.getStats',
                urls: 'here you url'
            }, function(response){
                alert(response[0].total_count)
            });
```

or https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?&method=links.getStats&urls=http://stackoverflow.com&format=json-strings